# How to add elements to array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a JSON object with multiple arrays inside and want to add entries to arrays. After that, I am putting the JSON entries in a pandas table format, but all entries in the table are empty. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from datetime import datetime

class A :
    t  = '{"W":[],"X":[],"Y":[],"Z":[]}'

    def updatet(w,x,y,z):
        b = json.loads(A.t)
        b["W"].append(w)
        b["X"].append(x)
        b["Y"].append(y)
        b["Z"].append(z)

        df = pd.DataFrame(eval(A.t))
        html = df.to_html()
        text_file = open("/tmp/index.html", "w")
        text_file.write(html)
        text_file.close()

    def addrecord():
        A.updatet("A","B","C","D")
        A.updatet("E","F","G","H")

a = A
a.addrecord()
```

output of file:

```
#cat /tmp/index.html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th></th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Modifying the parsed json object, like `b["W"].append(w)` will not change the value of `A.t`. If you parse a json string, and modify the parsed version, that won't change the original string. You'd need to do `df = pd.DataFrame(b)` if you want your changes to be reflected.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code to df = pd.DataFrame(b). Now I am able to get entry into the table. But the table has entries for E, F, G, and H and missing entries for A, B, C, and D. Is there a way to append?

Comment: Yes - right now you create a new dataframe each time, which means that only the last row will be kept. I recommend learning how to use instance variables in a class, like this tutorial: https://pynative.com/python-instance-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, below code, helped.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from datetime import datetime

class A :
    t  = '{"W":[],"X":[],"Y":[],"Z":[]}'

    def updatet(w,x,y,z):
        b = json.loads(A.t)
        print(b["W"].append(w))
        print(b["X"].append(x))
        print(b["Y"].append(y))
        print(b["Z"].append(z))

        df = pd.DataFrame(b)
        html = df.to_html()
        text_file = open("/tmp/index.html", "w")
        text_file.write(html)
        text_file.close()
        A.t = json.dumps(b)

    def addrecord():
        A.updatet("A","B","C","D")
        A.updatet("E","F","G","H")

a = A
a.addrecord()
```

File output:

```
# cat /tmp/index.html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th></th>
    <th>W</th>
    <th>X</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Z</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <th>0</th>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```